# unable to build my app

Tags: android, cross-platform, codenameone

Hi World App is running in simulator but not generating the BUILD files.

I am getting this error

```
goBlank:

testFail:

setupJavac:

jar:
     [echo] Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
     [echo]             code size and wider device support
     [copy] Copying 1 file to E:\rainforest\rfl1\rfl1-1\testcodenameone\build\tmp
    [javac] E:\rainforest\rfl1\rfl1-1\testcodenameone\build.xml:131: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to E:\rainforest\rfl1\rfl1-1\testcodenameone\build\tmp
      [jar] Building jar: E:\rainforest\rfl1\rfl1-1\testcodenameone\dist\testcodenameone.jar
    [javac] E:\rainforest\rfl1\rfl1-1\testcodenameone\build.xml:155: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

BUILD FAILED
E:\rainforest\rfl1\rfl1-1\testcodenameone\build.xml:155: Class not found: javac1.8

Total time: 3 seconds
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623848/codenameone-simulator-launch-issue

Answer (score 0):

You need Eclipse itself to run under JDK 1.7 (this needs to be configured via the Eclipse ini file). Also make sure JAVA_HOME points to JDK 1.7.